# "Positives changes on the cards" — meaning?

Tags: meaning

> **Positives** changes on the cards in Nigeria.

What does it mean? Is this correct usage?

Usually I have read "positive". I think it makes a lot of difference whether we use "positives" or  "positive" in this sentence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's either a typo or a mistranscription by the OP. There's no possible justification for appending an **s** to adjectival **positive**, and it doesn't "mean" anything..

Comment: check this out:http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/columns/positives-changes-on-the-cards-in-nigeria/article7065649.ece

Comment: Written by a non-native speaker, no doubt. Perhaps this would do better on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Man i just want to know if we positives makes any sense.i am unable to interpret what the writer is trying to  say.if would be great if you explain this.please

Comment: No, it *doesn't* make sense. The writer is simply making a mistake because he doesn't know English very well. Perhaps both he and you are prone to the *same* mistake because you both speak the same native language, in which adjectives *can* be modified in this way. But if that is so it's something you should be exploring on ELL, not here (this site isn't here to help non-native speakers learn basic English).

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Well, *on the cards* is idiomatic British English (and presumably this has transferred to Indian English). It indicates a likely occurrence.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: My ignorance. Thanks for enlightening me. No offense (sic) intended. Edited my answer.

Comment: It is the case that some adjectives in Hindi do inflect for number. I wonder if this is leaking into Indian English, and whether it's widespread enough to become an accepted part of that dialect. Currently I would guess that it's not accepted.

Comment: @Andrew: It's my understanding that almost none of the variations from "Standard English" in IE are in any meaningful sense "accepted". I've just read [English in Contemporary India](http://www.accu.or.jp/appreb/09/pdf33-2/33-2P005-007.pdf) by an academic who *speaks and writes in Indian English*. You'd find it hard to detect any deviations from Standard English there. For the most part, IE is just a bucket term for "mistakes that non-native Anglophones in *India* tend to make* (Indian schools teach SE, not IE).

Comment: Should be "*positive* changes *in* the cards", and it refers to having ones "cards read" by a person who is "card reader" or "medium" and who can supposedly tell the future.

Answer (score 1):

The headline is not correct. In English, the plural of (a) positive change is
- **positive changes**

That is, the adjective does not take a "plural" form to modify a plural noun (in other languages, such as Spanish, it would, but not in English.)

As for "on the cards":  Initially, this struck me as odd—the common AmE idiom is *in the cards*  (meaning something presumably will happen in future—or is predicted to happen). However, I have since been informed that "on the cards" is the usual idiomatic way to say this in BrE.

Comment: I had never heard "in the cards" but ngrams show both "in" and "on" are used.

Comment: You neglect to mention that "in the cards" is used more than 45x as often as "on the cards", and has never been less than 6x as popular (English corpus).  In BrE corpus, "in the cards" is used, recently, more than 20x as  often ( "on the cards" does not occur before 1825).      In AmE corpus, it's about 100x as often (with "on the cards" not occurring before 1850). So it seems "on the cards" is relatively rare on both sides of the pond. But I changed my answer to not call it "wrong". Nor is it obsolete or archaic; it's no rarer now than it was 100 years ago.

Comment: @Brian: I think you're massively overstating things. True, *It's **In** the cards* has become [more common than ***on*** in AmE over recent decades](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%27s+on+the+cards%2Cit%27s+in+the+cards&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20%27s%20on%20the%20cards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20%27s%20in%20the%20cards%3B%2Cc0), but nothing like 20-40 times more. And if you switch to the BrE corpus there you'll see ***in*** is still virtually unknown in BrE.

Comment: ...to me, *on the cards* in OP's citation is a perfectly ordinary idiom simply meaning ***likely***, and with no particular connection to fortune-telling. But the ***in*** version strongly implies that more literal sense to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I searched "in the cards, on the cards"; whereas you searched "it's in the cards, it's on the cards". That's why the discrepancy jn the ratios we found.

Comment: @Brian: Even with **it's**, some proportion of the hits will be for other senses, but at least it gets us closer to the truth. Note [this well-received comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192585/in-the-cards-or-on-the-cards#comment401957_192585) where the usage was previously addressed here. Checking NGram prevalence suggests ***on*** in BrE could be 2-3 times more common *per million words written* than ***in*** in AmE. To Brits, it's a fully assimilated idiom - we just *use* it, without thinking about [stacked] decks of cards, fortune-tellers, or how the preposition works.